# Simplest way of choosing a preferred variable value

Tags: javascript

I have 3 variables, that are not always set. `o1`, `o2`, `o3`.

I want to create a new variable as follows:

if none are set: `o4 = null`

if `o1` is set, `o4 = o1`, regarded of what the other are.

when `o1` is not set and `o2` is set: `o4 = o2`

So `o4 = o3` only gets set when 1 and 2 are not set.

==

I am now using a long switch, but I bet it can be done better.

JavaScript / jQuery

```
    var tmpl = '';

    if(data.o3 != null)
        tmpl = data.o3;

    if(data.o2 != null)
        tmpl = data.o2;

    if(data.o1 != null)
        tmpl = data.o1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `var o4 = o1 || o2 || o3`.

**Edit:** As per comments, this only works when values that might be set are not falsy. May be best to avoid this method, unless you're sure.

Comment: This doesn't work if` o1`, `o2` or `o3` can be legitimate falsey values like `"", false, 0, NaN, null` etc...

Comment: This works assuming the variables cannot be falsy values like `0`. And also if `o3` is not set at all then `o4` will end up as `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: was my first thought as well but it won't work for 0 for example and OP said the condition is `is set` not `is truthy` | edit: wow i'm slow :)

Comment: This does not really work for me, or I have another error in the code. Now in my code o1 and o2 are set, this method chooses o2, or did I do something wring.

Comment: @SaifBechan See above comments as to why this might not work for you. Other than that, the bug might be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: wow ok I did not see all the responded, had to reload. Guess I will need to read trough them.

Comment: yeah this works ok for me, I made a little type in my test, but not it's all good. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
o4 = o1 || o2 || o3 || null;
```

It will check each variable in order to see if it is falsy. If a value is truthy for any of the variables that value will be used. If none are truthy o4 will be set to null. null at the end is optional if you don't care what falsy value o4 has.

Edit: switched "set" to "truthy".

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (and a method that supports an arbitrary number of variables) would be to put your `o1, o2, o3` variables into an array:

```
getFirstDefined(array) {
    for var (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (typeof array[i] != "undefined") {
            return(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return(null);
}
```

Comment: +1 Good solution here. In my case the variables are set or not, so the solution of Adam will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EBcyx/1/)

```
function set(o1, o2, o3) {
    var o4 = o1 || o2 || o3 || null;
    console.log(o4);   //check o4
}

set()                  //o4 = null
set('foo1');           //o4 = foo1
set(null,'foo2');      //o4 = foo2
set(null,null,'foo3'); //o4 = foo3
```